# Error: Recaptcha Enterprise 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

Regrettably, I encountered an error while utilizing reCAPTCHA Enterprise. I had been using it without any issues, but unexpectedly, I received an error message "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded" one day. Consequently, I promptly disabled reCAPTCHA Enterprise. Upon reactivating it the following day, everything resumed functioning normally.

Could anyone offer insights into what might have caused this issue, please?

Comment: This is a customer service-related question that you should be asking them directly. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.